# distutils.core.setup console script entry point?

Tags: python, python-3.x, installation, distutils

I used to distribute my python programs with `setuptools.setup`.
But now I want to use `distutils.core.setup`.

With `setuptools` I used a code similar to this:

```
setup(
    name = "radish",
    version = "0.01.00",
    description = "Behaviour-Driven-Development tool for python",
    author = "Timo Furrer",
    author_email = "tuxtimo@gmail.com",
    url = "http://github.com/timofurrer/radish",
    packages = [ "radish", "radish/Writers" ],
    entry_points = { "console_scripts": [ "radish = radish.main:main", ] },
    package_data = { "radish": [ "*.md" ] }
    ...
)
```

I want to do the same with `distutils` - but there is no `entry_points` available.
How can I manage this? How can I specify my new command?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't, not with `distutils`. It does not support `entry_points`, that's a setuptools-only feature.

Use [`setuptools`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools/) instead; it supports Python 3.

Comment: Okay, thank you! So, distutils can only be used to install python modules and not to install "commands"?!

Comment: Exactly; `distutils` is also present in Python 2. `setuptools` is an extension to `distutils`.

Comment: Since July 2013 ``setuptools`` is the way to go.

Comment: @guettli: Indeed; `distutils` and `setuptools` have merged

Answer (score 2):

With distutils, scripts are just files, like this example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from radish.main import main
main()
```

In your setup script, you use the scripts parameter to list these files.

This works great on Unix and can work on Windows if people/installers set up file associations properly (no binary wrappers are generated, like what setuptools does).  A .py extension will be needed for Windows, and will be okay (unneeded and for many people ugly) on Unix.

Far from perfect, but can work if you audience is developers for example, or doesn’t use Windows.